# GroupBy function to retrieve the first row of every category with status as Success and order by UpdatedDate as latest

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table which stores the status of transaction in every category. Category for example say Credit card, debit Card etc. 1 might have 5 status stored for CC and 5 for DC. I want to group the categories, go through the status ordered by the updated Date and get the status.

```
status = ldstatusC.LoadCardStatus
  .Where(w => w.Status = "S")
  .OrderByDescending(sDate => sDate.Updated_Date)
  .GroupBy(gSt => gSt.CardType)
  .Select(s => new Models.MODEL_LoadCardStatus()
  {
      CardTypeID = s.CardTypeId,
      CardType = s.Key,
      transactionStatus = s.Status,
      UpdatedDate = s.updatedDate
  })
  .ToList<Models.MODEL_LoadCardStatus>();
```

With this code, Im getting the error as shown below.

> `IGrouping<string, LoadCardStatus>` does not contain a definition for `LoadCardStatus_Id` and no extension method `LoadCardStatus_Id`
>   accepting a first argument of type `IGrouping<string, LoadCardStatus>`
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)'

I googled it a lot but most group by are just used for getting the count.

Comment: If you have 5 status stored for CC and 5 for DC, do you want 2 results back, or 10 results back?

Comment: I want last updated successful status for both of it. Ie., I want 2 success status - 1 for CC and 1 for DC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each item produced by `GroupBy` is a group, you need to add `First()`, or `Min()`, or other aggregator method if you wish to access properties its individual items:

```
.Select(g => new Models.MODEL_LoadCardStatus {
    CardTypeID = g.First().CardTypeId,
    CardType = g.Key,
    transactionStatus = g.First().Status,
    UpdatedDate = g.Select(s => s.UpdateDate).Max()
})
```